# Inserting character in between words - R Language

Tags: regex, r

I have a dataset, In which one column has a values in the format of `[A-Z][A-Z][0-1][0-9][0-1][0-1][0-1][0-9][0-9]` ie, `AC1200019`

Now I want to convert this format to `[A-Z][A-Z][-][0-1][0-9][-][0-1][0-1][0-1][-][0-9][0-9]` ie, `AC-12-000-19`

Comment: Show your efforts, where is your work you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

```
([A-Z][A-Z])([0-1][0-9])([0-1][0-1][0-1])([0-9][0-9])
```

Try this.Replace by `$1-$2-$3-$4` or `\\1-\\2-\\3-\\4`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uK9cD8/5

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
gsub('^([A-Z]{2})([0-1][0-9])([0-1]{3})([0-9]{2})', '\\1-\\2-\\3-\\4', str1)
 #[1] "AC-12-000-19"
```

#### data

```
 str1 <- 'AC1200019'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the entire column has the same number of characters, here a simple version.

```
library(stringr)
x <- data.frame(X1 = c("AC1510018", "AC1200019", "BT1801007"))
paste(str_sub(x$X1,1,2), str_sub(x$X1,3,4),
      str_sub(x$X1,5,7), str_sub(x$X1,8,9) , sep= "-")
```

I like the dplyr suite so here a version using dplyr and tidyr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
x %>% 
  separate(X1, into = c("X2", "X3", "X4", "X5"), sep = c(2,4,7)) %>%
  unite("X1", X2, X3, X4, X5, sep="-")
```

or

```
x %>% 
  transmute(X2 = paste(str_sub(X1,1,2), str_sub(X1,3,4),
                       str_sub(X1,5,7), str_sub(X1,8,9) , sep= "-"))
```

Comment: If I understand your code, all of these are not considering the values in the positions.  OP clearly stated that first two positions are [A-Z], 3-4 as [0-1][0-9] etc.  So, as per OP's post, something like ACGD463AG should not change the string.

Comment: I see that now. It wasn't till after I posted that i noticed the regex tag.